# reactJS with IE8 in not working

Tags: internet-explorer-8, reactjs

Does reactjs works fine with IE8? I am using React v0.11.1.

Following code is NOT working in IE8. Works fine on all the other browsers

SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'isArray'
File: react.js, Line: 17372, Column: 37
SCRIPT5009: 'React' is undefined
File: myreact.js, Line: 3, Column: 1
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'map'
File: JSXTransformer.js, Line: 12637, Column: 3

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var MyComponent = React.createClass({displayName: 'MyComponent',

    getDefaultProps:function(){

            return{

                text:"",
                numbers:0
            }

    },

    getInitialState:function(){


        return {txt:"initial", id:0}
    },

    updateText: function(event){

        this.setState({text:event.target.value})
    },

    propTypes:{

        text:React.PropTypes.string,

        numbers: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired
    },



    render:function(){

        return (
                    React.DOM.div(null, 
                        Widget({text: this.state.text, update: this.updateText}), 
                        Widget({text: this.state.text, update: this.updateText})
                    )
            )
    }

});

var Widget = React.createClass({displayName: 'Widget', render:function(){

        return(
                React.DOM.div(null, 
                React.DOM.input({type: "text", onChange: this.props.update}), 
                React.DOM.div(null, this.props.text)

            )
            )
    }

});

React.renderComponent(
    MyComponent({text: "HI there", numbers: 34}), 
        document.getElementById("content")
    );
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is IE8 getting a script error when using Facebook's React.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19259427/why-is-ie8-getting-a-script-error-when-using-facebooks-react-js)

Comment: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/working-with-the-browser.html#browser-support-and-polyfills

Comment: thanks for your comments, I included es5Shim.js and es5Sham.js. It works fine now.

Comment: I've collected some issues that might broke IE8, please check it if you need to make your React app work in IE8 https://github.com/xcatliu/react-ie8

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the following shims/pollyfills as noted in the [react docs](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/working-with-the-browser.html#polyfills-needed-to-support-older-browsers). [es5-shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim) will resolve the specific isArray bug you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to launch my React app in IE8 using the following code:
**App.js:**

```
require('core-js'); //Important!
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Application = React.createClass({ ... });
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Application,null), document.getElementById("app-container"));
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.5.7/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.5.7/es5-sham.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app-container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comments: `bundle.js` will be loaded after `es5-shim/es5-sham` because of `defer` html attribute

Comment: I didn't use ES6 in my project