# Where should I insert '@babel/polyfill' into?: main.js or each modules

Tags: javascript, babeljs, polyfills

I'm trying to implement web application using Babel 7, `@babel/preset-env` and `@babel/polyfill`.

```js
// main.js
import a from 'a';

a.doSomething()
```

```js
// a.js
export default class {
    doSomething() {
        // assume that here is some code that needs polyfills
    }
}
```

If I should insert `import '@babel/polyfill'` to support old browsers, where should it be, either in main.js or a.js, or both of them?

Comment: Solved: Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53142387/9765744).