# How to use babel/corejs3/webpack correctly for IE11?

Tags: javascript, webpack, internet-explorer-11, babeljs, core-js

With my current config (see below), I'm getting this error:

```
   [object Error]{description: "Argument ob...", message: "Argument ob...", name: "TypeError", number: -2147418113, stack: "TypeError: ...", Symbol()_7.bs7gi3oa3wi: undefined}
```

I tried to dig based on `Symbol()_ ... : undefined}` but I couldn't find any clear indication.

This is my `.babel.config.js`:

```
module.exports = function (api) {
    api.cache(true);
    const presets = [
      [
        '@babel/preset-env',
        {
         // modules: false,
          corejs:"3.6.4",
          useBuiltIns: 'usage',
          targets: {
            browsers: [
              "edge >= 16",
              "safari >= 9",
              "firefox >= 57",
              "ie >= 11",
              "ios >= 9",
              "chrome >= 49"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    ];
    const plugins= [
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { decoratorsBeforeExport: true }],
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }]
    ];
    return {
      presets,
      plugins
    }
  }
```

This is my `webpackconfig.js`

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
       // exclude: /node_modules/,
       exclude : [
        /\bcore-js\b/,
        /\bwebpack\/buildin\b/
      ],
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options:{
            sourceType: "unambiguous"
          }
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  devtool:"cheap-source-map",
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js'],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: 'shim.js',
  }
};
```

I've also tried many alternatives, this is my current one, with `entry:"usage"` and not excluding `node_modules`.

This is from my `package.json`:

```js
 "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.5",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "webpack": "^4.42.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^1.7.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "ismobilejs": "^1.0.3",
    "localforage": "1.7.3",
    "postmate": "^1.5.2",
    "uuid": "^7.0.3"
  }
```

Error seems to come from the first invocation of the [Postmate](https://github.com/dollarshaveclub/postmate) library i.e. `new Postmate({...})` (I have a `console.log` just before). Prior to this call, I have one to `localforage` and the promise complete succesfully.

Comment: It may be a good idea to set up a https://codesandbox.io/ so we see what you actually want to do

Comment: Can you post the detailed error message? As mfeineis said, you could create a sample to reproduce the problem. Besides, from you description, it seems that you want to using core-js with babel and webpack, can you tell us which version are you using? And here are some related threads, you could check them: [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56799222/) [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56032059/) and [Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31122193/).

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT I updated my current config and I added more details.

Comment: Whether this issue only occurs in IE 11 browser, try to check it using different browsers? If this issue only occurs in IE 11 browser, perhaps the issue is related to the Postmate, and might be you have to install the polyfill for IE browser. You could contact Postmate to confirm it or feedback this issue to [Postmate issue forum](https://github.com/dollarshaveclub/postmate/issues). Besides, from your question description, the error message is "Argument ob...", can you post the complete error message?

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT This is the full top-level error message from the console, the stack trace under is mostly empty except to repeat the Symbol()_... undefined. Also I know that Postmate can run with IE11 so the issue is not on their side. It works on Chromi(um), "old" Edge, Safari and Firefox.

Comment: Please show also your package.json. The problem with symbol can be related to untranspiled packages under your node_modules folder.

Comment: @nickbullock posted my package.json, like you can see from the webpack config, I'm not excluding node_modules currently.

Answer (score 14):

## Using `useBuiltIns: "usage"`

---

You'll have to normally import the modules you want to use (*i.g. Postmate*) inside your code entry file; no polyfills; every polyfill used will be handled accordingly by `@babel/preset-env`. Also, the version of `corejs` in `@babel/preset-env` has to be a single number (*i.e. `3` or `2`*).

#### Contents of `babel.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  const presets = [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        corejs : {
          version : "3",
          proposals : true
        },
        useBuiltIns: 'usage',
        targets: {
          browsers: [
            "edge >= 16",
            "safari >= 9",
            "firefox >= 57",
            "ie >= 11",
            "ios >= 9",
            "chrome >= 49"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  ];
  const plugins= [
      ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { decoratorsBeforeExport: true }],
      ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }]
  ];
  return {
    presets,
    plugins
  }
}
```

#### Contents of `webpackconfig.js`:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: [
          /\bcore-js\b/,
          /\bwebpack\/buildin\b/
        ],
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            babelrc: false,
            configFile: path.resolve(__dirname, 'babel.config.js'),
            compact: false,
            cacheDirectory: true,
            sourceMaps: false,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  devtool: "cheap-source-map",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: 'shim.js',
  }
}
```

#### Contents of entry JS file `src/index.js`:

```js
import Postmate from 'postmate';

// Postmate and rest of the code
...
```

It will generate:

```bash
dist/shim.js      177K
dist/shim.js.map  140K
```

You can test an online distributed example working using `useBuiltIns: "usage"` in **IE 11** here: https://zikro.gr/dbg/so/61044894/usage/. (*The child iFrame has a button that changes parent window background color to a random color*)

You can find a repository with the whole project and the **usage example branch** in this Github repository/branch: https://github.com/clytras/ie11-postmate/tree/usage

## Using `useBuiltIns: "entry"`

---

According to this issue disqussion ["using Symbol causes exception in IE11"](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/issues/514), you have to:

1. Exclude `@babel-runtime` and `core-js` in the rule for `.js` files.
2. Have `corejs: "3"` and `useBuiltIns: 'entry'` to `@babel/preset-env` preset inside `babel.config.js` file.
3. There have to be `core-js/stable` and `postmate` imports inside your entry source JS file.

#### Contents of `babel.config.js`:

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  const presets = [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        corejs:"3",
        useBuiltIns: 'entry',
        targets: {
          browsers: [
            "edge >= 16",
            "safari >= 9",
            "firefox >= 57",
            "ie >= 11",
            "ios >= 9",
            "chrome >= 49"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  ];
  const plugins= [
      ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { decoratorsBeforeExport: true }],
      ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }]
  ];
  return {
    presets,
    plugins
  }
}
```

#### Contents of `webpackconfig.js`:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /@babel(?:\/|\\{1,2})runtime|core-js/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            babelrc: false,
            configFile: path.resolve(__dirname, 'babel.config.js'),
            compact: false,
            cacheDirectory: true,
            sourceMaps: false,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  devtool:"cheap-source-map",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: 'shim.js',
  }
}
```

#### Contents of entry JS file `src/index.js`:

```js
import 'core-js/stable';
window.Postmate = require('postmate/build/postmate.min.js');

// Postmate and rest of the code
...
```

It will generate:

```bash
dist/shim.js      641K
dist/shim.js.map  459K
```

You can test in **IE 11** here: https://zikro.gr/dbg/so/61044894/.

Comment: Are you confifent that it can't be achieved with entry:"usage"?

Comment: Why shouldn't be confident? Using `usage`, imports for polyfills will be added when they are used. You can check it [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#usebuiltins-usage). Did you try the link that uses `Postmate` in IE11? It works and properly adds the `Symbol` polyfills so `Postmate` won't fail in IE11. What considerations do you have regarding any problems?

Comment: Your answer is using "entry" not "usage" and it seems to indicate that it can't work with "usage".

Comment: I am pretty aware what my answer uses; I wrote it and I have tested it. I just pointed out what usage is for and its documentation. My question is, what's wrong using `entry` instead of `usage` to cover IE11 and even older IE versions support?

Comment: @Rhangaun please check my updated answer. I've included `useBuiltIns: 'usage'` along with `useBuiltIns: 'entry'`. Maybe your issue is that you're not importing modules such as `postmate`.

Comment: Those `excludes` saved me. Babel kept trying to polyfill `core-js` which was causing some weird errors for me.

Comment: thanks so much for your pretty awesome and detailed answer! it helped a lot

Answer (score 1):

You're probably missing some imports, I'd suggest looking at what [react-app-polyfills](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-app-polyfill/ie11.js) imports under the hood for IE11 support - the error message relates to `Symbol`. `core-js>=3` no longer imports everything that IE11 needs with `core-js/stable`. At the time of this writing this might suffice:

```
// If  you need `fetch` or `Object.assign`
npm install whatwg-fetch object-assign
```

```
// Make sure we're in a Browser-like environment before importing polyfills
// This prevents `fetch()` from being imported in a Node test environment
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  // fetch() polyfill for making API calls.
  require('whatwg-fetch');
}

// Object.assign() is commonly used with React.
// It will use the native implementation if it's present and isn't buggy.
Object.assign = require('object-assign');

/// This may rid you of your error message

// Support for...of (a commonly used syntax feature that requires Symbols)
require('core-js/features/symbol');
// Support iterable spread (...Set, ...Map)
require('core-js/features/array/from');
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I've tried with "core-js" (without /stable) just to see if it makes a difference, but I'm still getting the same error (symbol related).

Comment: Thanks, manually install whatwg-fetch object-assign fixed it, then I updated `react-app-polyfill` to latest and it works. So my package was outdated